# Wireless adaptor no longer works on ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers

I have a tp link ac1200 and I've used (successfully) [this](http://swkstudios.com/tutorials/ubuntu/ubuntu-14-04-installing-tp-link-ac1200-t4u/) guide to get the adaptor (rtl8812au) working on ubuntu 14.04 (dual booted with windows).

Today, I turn on my pc and the adaptor is no longer powering up (no flashing lights as usual) when I boot into ubuntu (windows works fine).

I've done all the usual reboot/reinstall/unplug/replug etc with no effect. I am obviously perplexed and I really need this to work now!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit:
I now have an error message on login:
/usr/lib/upower/upowerd has crashed with SIGABRT in __libc_message() 
Apparently that was iPhone related.

However, lsusb gives only Linux, Intel USB devices and one blank

dmesg tells me that:
8812au: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

Edit: Solved!

This issue appears when the kernel updates and so you have to recompile everything. Use this [script](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/issues/23) :

```
MODULE="rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux"
MODULE_VERSION="1.0"
MODULE_SRC_PATH="/usr/src/"

dkms remove "${MODULE}/${MODULE_VERSION}" --all
dkms add "${MODULE}/${MODULE_VERSION}"
dkms build "${MODULE}/${MODULE_VERSION}"
dkms install --force "${MODULE}/${MODULE_VERSION}"
```

save as `something.sh` somewhere and run using `sudo sh somthing.sh`.

Comment: I updated my tutorial at [swkstudios.com](http://swkstudios.com/tutorials/ubuntu/ubuntu-14-04-installing-tp-link-ac1200-t4u/) to reflect your post here. Do you mind double checking it since I do not have this device anymore?

Answer (score 0):

See:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kernel/rtl8812au-dkms
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/universe/base/rtl8812au-dkms

This kernel module is an ubuntu package, you can install it or reinstall it to rebuild it for your kernel if it gets updated:

If the package is not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

If the package is installed and your kernel version changes:

```
sudo apt-get remove rtl8812au-dkms
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```